# Why can I not put a fraction inside of a pmatrix?

Tags: math-mode, errors, compiling, matrices, fractions

So I'm trying to typeset a formula that contains a vector with two values that are fractions.  This, unfortunately, is not working.  Here is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{pmatrix}\frac{x}{\|\overrightarrow{v}\|}\\ 
   \frac{y}{\|\overrightarrow{v}\|}\\ \end{pmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?  It gave me an error when I tried to compile it, and the problem is that the fractions won't work inside the pmatrix (yet i've seen it done before!)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have close to working code to start from that shows all of the relevant packages etc that are being used. This said, rather than `\bftext` you probably want `\textbf` or, better still, `\mathbf` since this appears to be mathematics.

Comment: @Andrew, okay, fixed the bolded text. it still doesn't work though.

Comment: As I said, please expand to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).  It's hard to help given incomplete information as to what you are doing.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure how I can minimalize this even more.  I simply cannot find where in this equation the problem is.

Comment: A minimal working example is something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x}{\| \overrightarrow{v} \|}\\ \frac{y}{\|
\overrightarrow{v} \|}\\ \end{pmatrix}.
\]
\end{document}`. The thing is that this does work, so you must have made a mistake somewhere else. As long as you do not provide a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and shows the problem, you cannot be helped.

Comment: @marmot apologies, I was using codecogs.org to render the latex and insert it into a google doc for an essay.  I would have written the whole thing in latex but my teacher only want's google docs.

Comment: @Jodast What you added now, is, I am afraid, even worse, since this is not a compilable code. You are supposed to write a mini document which can be compiled. Of course, if you are using google doc, this is a different story, and I have no clue how that works. Yet you are to append the information that this is for google docs to your question. Most likely your problem will be solved by adding  `$`s before and after the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not in mathmode. Adding a pair of `\[  \]` around the formula works, but the result can be improved. Here is a code with `amsmath` and the `esvect` package, which has nicer arrow tips (8 possibilities):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[f]{esvect}
\usepackage{bigstrut} 

\begin{document}

\[ \hat{u} = \begin{pmatrix}\cfrac{x}{\| \vv{v}\|}\\ \cfrac{y}{\| \vv{v} \|\bigstrut[b]}
\end{pmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]